# Find All Subnets in AD

Tags: search, active-directory, subnet

I'm trying to retrieve all the subnets in our AD.
I need the values from the cn, location, description and Site attributes.
I can see these attributes when i open the "Active Directory Sites and Services" app and select "subnets"

I found some code which i thought would retrieve these values

```
        Forest myForest = Forest.GetCurrentForest();
        ReadOnlySiteCollection mySites = default(ReadOnlySiteCollection);
        ActiveDirectorySubnetCollection mySubnets = default(ActiveDirectorySubnetCollection);
        int iEnumSites = 0;
        int iEnumSubnets = 0;
        mySites = myForest.Sites;
       Dictionary<string, Subnet> Subnets = new Dictionary<string, Subnet>();
        //for each site loop through
        for (iEnumSites = 0;  iEnumSites < mySites.Count -1; iEnumSites++)
        {
         // for each subnet in each site loop through
         mySubnets = mySites[iEnumSites].Subnets;
            for (iEnumSubnets = 0 ; iEnumSubnets < mySubnets.Count -1; iEnumSubnets++)
            {

                Subnet s = new Subnet(mySubnets[iEnumSubnets].Name, mySubnet[iEnumSubnets].Site, mySubnets[iEnumSubnets].Location,"");
                Subnets.Add(s.GetKey(), s);
            }

        }
```

However, the "Description" attribute isn't there.  Each Subnet only exposes 3 properties/attributes.
Does anyone know how i can get access to all the Attributes on all our subnets ?

Thanks

Erck

Answer (score 0):

ok so when you have a reference to an object in AD you can do a `GetDirectoryEntry` on it

```
Forest myForest = Forest.GetCurrentForest();
ReadOnlySiteCollection mySites = default(ReadOnlySiteCollection);
ActiveDirectorySubnetCollection mySubnets = default(ActiveDirectorySubnetCollection);
int iEnumSites = 0;
int iEnumSubnets = 0;
mySites = myForest.Sites;
Dictionary<string, Subnet> Subnets = new Dictionary<string, Subnet>();
//for each site loop through
for (iEnumSites = 0;  iEnumSites < mySites.Count -1; iEnumSites++)
{
   // for each subnet in each site loop through
   mySubnets = mySites[iEnumSites].Subnets;
   for (iEnumSubnets = 0 ; iEnumSubnets < mySubnets.Count -1; iEnumSubnets++)
   {
        var ent= mySubnet[iEnumSubnets].GetDirectoryEntry();

        // you now have access to all attributes e.g the description attribute
        string.Join(",",ent.Properties["description"].Cast<object>().Select(v => Convert.ToString(v)))
   }

}
```

and any other attribute you want.